# Loading from an Xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Okay so this is very basic but I've literally started learning how to read an XML document today and i usually find answers more comprehensive on here than on online guides. Essentially i'm coding a Pokemon game which uses an XML file to load all the stats (its one i swiped from someone else).The user will input a Pokemon and i then want to read the Base Stats of the Pokemon from the XML file, to give a template, this would be one of the Pokemon:

```
<Pokemon>
   <Name>Bulbasaur</Name>

   <BaseStats>
     <Health>5</Health>
     <Attack>5</Attack>
     <Defense>5</Defense>
     <SpecialAttack>7</SpecialAttack>
     <SpecialDefense>7</SpecialDefense>
     <Speed>5</Speed>
   </BaseStats>
</Pokemon>
```

The code ive tried to use is:

```
XDocument pokemonDoc = XDocument.Load(@"File Path Here");
        while(pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Elements("Name").ToString() == cbSpecies.SelectedText)
        {
            var Stats = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Elements("BaseStats");
        }
```

but this just returns pokemonDoc as null, any idea where im going wrong?

**NOTE:**

cbSpeciesSelect is where the user selects which species of pokemon they want.

The File Path definitely works as i've used it already in my program

The while loop never actually starts

Comment: Is there an `xml declaration` in your xml file?

Comment: Im not really too sure what that is, the top of the xml file shows this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPokemon xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

Comment: It may be cleaner to serialize/deserialize directly to an object as a first step.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: have you confirmed that the file path is correct...maybe try absolute path to be sure?

Comment: The file path is absolute, i just didn't post it with the code, it definitely works trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var pokemon = doc.Descendants("Pokemon").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                health = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Health"),
                attack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Attack"),
                defense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Defense"),
                specialAttack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialAttack"),
                specialDefense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialDefense"),
                speed = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Speed"),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code:

```
foreach(var e in pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Elements("Name"))
{
    if(e.Value==cbSpecies.SelectedText)
    {
        var Stats = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Elements("BaseStats");
    }
}
```